`<h2>` and `<h3>` in a site menu? - considering SEO vs a11y requirements
We're building a new site and encounter a question on how to expose the main navigation menu in terms of HTML. Note that the site menu is rather on the large side with submenus for different countries, many topics sections, etc.
We have one side who says, for accessibility reasons, it's preferred to have lots of <h2> and <h3> elements for each entry or subentry in the menu, as screen readers will be able to understand these tags better than <div> elements even if aria roles are applied to the latter.
Note that we'll have the menu in the <nav> section, and the contents inside a <main> element.
The SEO people say, having lots of <h2> and <h3> elements is bad for SEO because it disrupts the page structure, even if they are inside the <nav> section.
I couldn't find anything specific regarding this question.
ChatGPT seems to side with the SEO side: https://chatgpt.com/share/675ff5d7-2308-800f-b930-8fb279b04dc2
What do the real humans think? :-)

I think if you are putting the heading structure within nav I think you will be ok from a SEO and accessibility POV. Google will see all the content in the nav and understand this is navigational and more than likely wouldn't have much impact on the organic signals. Personally, I try to use headings for the main, on page content rather than in the navigation.

Usually try and be as semantic as possible.  Are they unclickable headings dividing up the separate menus (in which case h2/h3 sounds right), or menu items leading to a landing page, in which case they should probably be part of the menu list itself (with aria-label on the main nav tag).

A best practice recommended by the W3C's Web Accessibility Initiative for marking up navigation menus is to use a <ul> tag inside the semantic <nav> tag, with each child <li> tag containing a navigation link. For example:
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item1">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item2">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/item3">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

This pattern has the benefit of avoiding the use of <h2> and <h3> tags, which from an SEO perspective should be reserved to the main content, while still providing a form of hierarchical structure for the user. From an accessibility perspective, this could also be beneficial, as it reduces the number of heading tags in each page, which gives us a less "busy," more focused document outline.
If your menu has multiple levels, you can use nested lists to represent the hierarchical structure of the menu. For example:
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="/item1">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item1-1">Sub-item 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item1-2">Sub-item 1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/item2">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item2-1">Sub-item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item2-2">Sub-item 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/item3">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item3-1">Sub-item 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item3-2">Sub-item 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

And if your navigation menu includes "headings" that are not links, feel free to simply not link them, or use a <strong> or <b> tag to highlight them. For example:
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <b>Item 1</b>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item1-1">Sub-item 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item1-2">Sub-item 1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Item 2</b>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item2-1">Sub-item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item2-2">Sub-item 2.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Item 3</b>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item3-1">Sub-item 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/item1/sub-item3-2">Sub-item 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

